# I wonder how to memoize stroke in swift

Tags: swift, uiview, uikit, pencilkit

I recently ventured into utilizing Swift's UIKit to create a custom PencilKit.

My approach involves sampling information about points every time the pencil touches the screen, storing this data in a format like

strokeCollection = {strokes: [Stroke], drawingStroke: Stroke?}

and overriding the UIView's draw method to redraw the view each time the strokeCollection is updated. However, as more strokes are drawn, the app begins to significantly slow down due to the need to redraw every stroke continually.

In React Native Skia, I've used the "createPicture" method to leverage the "Picture" component, keeping previously drawn strokes intact and preventing the app from slowing down. I'm curious if there's a similar technique available in Swift or if you might have other suggestions to address this issue.

My original code draws for every stroke every time as below.

```
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
            UIColor.clear.set()
            UIRectFill(rect)
            
            // saved strokes
            if let strokeCollection = strokeCollection {
                if strokeToDraw != nil {
                    for stroke in strokeCollection.strokes {
                        draw(stroke: stroke, in: rect)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            // currently drawing stroke
            if let stroke = strokeToDraw {
                draw(stroke: stroke, in: rect)
            }
        }

func draw(stroke: Stroke, in rect: CGRect) {
        guard stroke.samples.isEmpty == false else { return }
        
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        var previousSample: StrokeSample?
        
        for sample in stroke.samples {
            if let prev = previousSample {
                let midPoint = midpoint(first: prev.location, second: sample.location)
                
                path.addQuadCurve(to: midPoint, controlPoint: prev.location)
            } else {
                path.move(to: sample.location)
            }
            previousSample = sample
        }
        
        if let lastSample = previousSample {
            path.addLine(to: lastSample.location)
        }
        
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            switch stroke.type {
            case .pen, .marker:
                context.setBlendMode(.normal)
                context.addPath(path.cgPath)
                context.setStrokeColor(stroke.color.cgColor)
                context.setLineWidth(stroke.width * 2)
                context.setAlpha(stroke.opacity)
                context.setLineCap(.round)
                context.setLineJoin(.round)
                context.strokePath()
            case .eraser:
                context.setBlendMode(.clear)
                context.addPath(path.cgPath)
                context.setStrokeColor(stroke.color.cgColor)
                context.setLineWidth(stroke.width * 2)
                context.setAlpha(stroke.opacity)
                context.setLineCap(.round)
                context.setLineJoin(.round)
                context.strokePath()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: In general, you should avoid implementing `draw(rect:)` in your apps. That forces the drawing code onto the main thread and the CPU, and prevents the GPU from rendering it. I would suggest refactoring your code to use CAShapeLayers, and let the system draw them for you.

Comment: Your current code has nested loops that build and draw UIBezierPaths. That is a lot of work to do in `draw(rect:)`. It would be faster to build the paths once and reuse them. (But faster still to build your paths and install them into a shape layer.)

Comment: Thanks for your great comments. As you suggested I changed my code to save UIBezierPaths and reuse when they are needed, and it really helped!! I also tried to create CAShapeLayer everytime I stroke, but it made my app really slow... Maybe my code had some problems. I think now I can figure out what should I work on. Thank you!!